# Bim360 Docs model translation jobs not triggered

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I've been following [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/) tutorial to successfully upload Revit & AutoCad files to Bim360 Docs using 2-legged tokens. I am also using the 'x-user-id' header.

The problem I'm having is after the model is published to Bim360 docs, it’s not viewable in the browser and derivatives are empty (see below). It appears that the model translation job never occurs. Isn’t this supposed to happen automatically for Bim360 Docs files? Could the 2-legged token be hindering this process? Is there another step I'm missing?

I've even tried to manually kick off a translation job after uploading the file by calling [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) API with NO success.

This image is the result of calling the [manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) API.

[empty derivatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KjRa.png)

Comment: Hello Sam, I have replied to your email to Forge Help. Could you check the manifest from your side again? I checked the backend log, this translation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting it to us. Our engineering team is investigating the problem. But you should see the progress status 100% now, please haveing a try, thanks!

Comment: The manifest status has show complete the whole time. The derivatives are still empty.

Comment: Hi Sam, I logged it as RVTLMV-1678